# Почему во время события keypress в JQuery, не обрабатывается последний символ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Начинаю знакомиться с JQuery. Смотрю мини [видео-гайд](https://youtu.be/S3kyIGoJFZ8?t=420).

Там на 7 минуте демонстрируется пример, когда мы что-то вводим в input и этот текст передается/вписывается в другой блок кода с определенным id'шником.
Но когда мы передаем текст из input при keypress, то последний напечатанный символ не передается. Если поменять событие на keyup, то все становится нормально.

Сделал простенькое подобие и да, так и работает.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').keypress(function(){
      $('span').text(', ' + $(this).val())
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Введите текст" id="text">
</form>
<p>Привет<span id="userName"></span>!</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Собственно почему при событии keypress "не передается" последний символ?
Ведь keypress - это когда мы нажимаем и отпускаем клавишу на клавиатуре, а когда мы печатаем текст в input, то в любом случае мы полностью нажимаем на клавишу и отпускаем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ведь `keypress` - это когда мы нажимаем и отпускаем клавишу на клавиатуре

Вы пробуйте не только видео-гайды смотреть, но и  в [документацию](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) заглядывать. Оф.доки должны быть для вас первоочередным источником информации.

> Note: as the keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.
>
> The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers keyboard input. **This is similar to the keydown event,** except that modifier and non-printing keys such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger keydown events but not keypress events. Other differences between the two events may arise depending on platform and browser.

Во-первых, написано, что событие нет четкой спецификации, и поведение может варьироваться в зависимости от браузера. Во-вторых черным по белому указано, что событие схоже с `keydown`, за исключением спец.клавиш. Отсюда должно быть очевидно, по какой причине вы получаете, то что получаете, а не то что фантазируете.

Comment: ... работает схоже с `keydown`. Я заменил `keypress` на `keydown` и да, функциональность кода не поменялась, но вопрос все же остался. Почему последний нажатый символ не записывается в `span`? Почитал документацию: https://api.jquery.com/keydown/ там про это ничего не написано

Comment: @ЕгорСпириади очевидно, потому что сначала происходит keydown, затем изменение значения, а потом keyup ?

Comment: то есть `keydown` срабатывает сразу после нажатия клавиши, но до передачи значения в `input`? Где про это можно подробнее узнать?

Comment: @ЕгорСпириади в стандарте и почитать: [_"This event type MUST be dispatched before the `beforeinput`, `input`, and `keyup` events associated with the same key."_](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#events-keyboard-types)